# Verify RSA signature in openssl0.9.8a

Tags: rsa, digital-signature

I'm developping a C++ application based on openssl0.9.8a API, i need to verify an RSA signature (4096 bit RSA key) using an RSA public key "pubkey"

```
const EVP_MD* md = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA512");
if (!md) return false;
if(EVP_DigestInit_ex(ctx, md, NULL)<=0) return false;
if(EVP_DigestVerifyInit( ctx, NULL, md, NULL, pubKey)<=0) return false;
if (EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx, Msg, MsgLen) <= 0) return false;
int res = EVP_DigestFinal_ex(ctx, MsgHash, &MsgHashLen);
```

The problem is "EVP_DigestVerifyInit" function is not defined in openssl0.9.8a, is there any other alternative? Is there an other way to verify an RSA signature in openssl0.9.8a?

Comment: FWIW: OpenSSL 0.9.8 went out of support on 31 Dec 2015.  You really should upgrade to a supported 1.0.x or 1.1.x. https://www.openssl.org/policies/releasestrat.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verify RSA signature in openssl0.9.8a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044548/verify-rsa-signature-in-openssl0-9-8a)

Comment: Don't cross post please (post on different sites). The other one on crypto was being migrated.